# What does status='Failed' in where condition in a AsyncApexJob query returns?

Tags: batch, asyncapexjob

Can someone explain as to what is returned when I'm querying AsyncApexJob object with  status set in where condition as 'Failed'?

Comment: A batch, @future method or Queueable job that has failed for X reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The batch failed to process the full request due to an unexpected
>   error, such as the request being compressed with an unsupported
>   format, or an internal server error. Even if the batch failed, some
>   records could have been completed successfully. If the
>   numberRecordsProcessed field in the response is greater than zero, you
>   should get the results to see which records were processed, and if
>   they were successful.

Complete details are given [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_batches_interpret_status.htm)